# how to convert yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss to mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm am/pm in react native

Tags: datetime, react-native

I have a string as 2018-10-15 11:40:39 and I have to convert this into a string like 10-15-2018 11:40 AM. i'm beginner in react native.

Comment: try momentjs `npm install moment --save`

Comment: @TamilSelvanC then? how to convert

Comment: try `moment('2018-10-15 13:40:39').format('M-D-YYYY hh:mm a')`

Comment: @TamilSelvanC Thanks bro.

Answer (score 4):

From the root of your project just run:

```
npm install moment --save
```

Then you can import it in your code:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

For date convert, use below code

```
console.log( moment('2018-01-01 13:40:39').format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm a') );
```

```js
alert( moment('2018-01-01 13:40:39').format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm a') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled few days and then created a solution.

```
function padTwoDigits(num: number) {
  return num.toString().padStart(2, "0");
}

function dateInYyyyMmDdHhMmSs(date: Date, dateDiveder: string = "-") {
  
  return (
    [
      date.getFullYear(),
      padTwoDigits(date.getMonth() + 1),
      padTwoDigits(date.getDate()),
    ].join(dateDiveder) +
    " " +
    [
      padTwoDigits(date.getHours()),
      padTwoDigits(date.getMinutes()),
      padTwoDigits(date.getSeconds()),
    ].join(":")
  );
}
console.log(dateInYyyyMmDdHhMmSs(new Date(‘May 04, 2030 10:20:07’)));
console.log(dateInYyyyMmDdHhMmSs(new Date(‘May 04, 2030 10:20:07’), '/'));
```